# MySQL accepting local, local network and external connections with bind-address?

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets, iptables

I'd like to access MySQL internally (localhost), externally (from the machine's external ip), as well as by it's local network address. The idea is that requests from our webserver, which is also apart of the same network, won't have to leave the local network and come back in.

The problem I have is getting MySQL to accept requests to it's local address, as mf.cnf has the "bind-address" option set as the machine's external ip.

I've read that setting bind-address 0.0.0.0 as an option, but is that the most ideal approach? I would probably need to setup iptables to drop any requests to mysql/3306 that don't come from my approved ip's.

That said, a tracert from the web server machine to mysql machine's external ip is only two hops, is it even worth it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you just need to accept MySQL connections from all "directions"? `bind 0.0.0.0:3306` would be enough. Why do you want to use iptables?